# Is it ever useful to cancel an asyncio future?

Tags: future, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand the use of Future.cancel() with `asyncio`. The Python documentation is very light on this. I've had no success with existing questions on here or search engines.  I just want to understand happens when a task is awaiting a future which is cancelled.

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio 

async def foo(future):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    future.cancel()

async def bar(future):
    await future
    print("hi")

async def baz(future):
    await bar(future)
    print("ho")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = loop.create_future()
loop.create_task(baz(future))
loop.create_task(foo(future))
loop.run_forever()
```

`"hi"` is not seen printed. So I initially guessed `bar` was returning at the line `await future` in the case of a cancel.

However, `"ho"` is not printed either. So it seems logical that cancelling a future never yields back to tasks awaiting it? But then these tasks are sitting in the event loop forever? This seems undesirable, where have I misunderstood?

Comment: The `await future` statement raises an [asyncio.CancelledError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) exception. Use a `try/except` statement if you want to ignore the cancellation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the answer lies in the documentation, but you have to look for it a bit. First, a reminder of what it means to *await* a future:

```py
# the expression:
x = await future

# is equivalent to:
... magically suspend the coroutine until the future.done() becomes true ...
x = future.result()
```

In other words, once the execution of the coroutine that contains `await` resumes, the value of the `await` statement will be the `result()` of the awaited future.

The question is: when you cancel a future, what is its result? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.result) says:

> If the Future has been *cancelled*, this method raises a `CancelledError` exception.

So when someone cancel a future you awaited, the `await future` expression will raise an exception! This neatly explains why `bar` doesn't print `hi` (because `await future` has raised), and why `baz` doesn't print `ho` (because `await bar(...)` has raised).

A traceback is never printed because `loop.create_task` spawns the coroutine in the "background" (of sorts) - if no one inspects the return value, the exception will be lost. And since you threw away the [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) object returned by `create_task` and used `run_forever` to have the loop running forever, the loop just continues running, waiting (forever) for new tasks to somehow arrive.

If you changed the code to actually collect the result of `bar`, you would easily observe the `CancelledError`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    loop.create_task(foo(future))
    loop.run_until_complete(baz(future))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 19, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(baz(future))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise CancelledError
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```